# Haskell Check if a list of Int's is complete

Tags: list, haskell

Not easy way to explain this, but I will try. I think i'm confusing my method with some C, but here it goes:

I want to check if a list is complete, like this:

```
main> check 1 [1,3,4,5]
False

main> check 1 [1,2,3,4]
True
```

It's a finite list, and the list doesn't have to be ordered. But inside the list there most be the number that misses to be True. In the first case it's the number 2.

This is my version, but it doesn't even compile.

```
check :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
check n [] = False
check n x | n/=(maximum x) = elem n x && check (n+1) x
          | otherwise = False
```

Answer (score 4):

So if I understand this correctly, you want to check to see that all the elements in a list form a sequence without gaps when sorted.  Here's one way:

```
noGaps :: (Enum a, Ord a) => [a] -> Bool
noGaps xs = all (`elem` xs) [minimum xs .. maximum xs]
```

`[minimum xs .. maximum xs]` creates a sequential list of all values from the lowest to the highest value.  Then you just check that they are `all` `elem`ents of the original list.

Comment: thank you for providing a correct signature for the `check` function, which I wasn't able to come up with (I just learned how to qualify a type as belonging to two different typeclasses!).

Answer (score 3):

Your function doesn't compile because your type constraints are greater than what you declare them as. You say that `a` only needs to be an instance of `Eq` - but then you add something to it, which requires it to be an instance of `Num`. The way you use the function also doesn't make sense with the signature you declared - `check [1,2,3,4]` is a `Bool` in your example, but in the code you gave it would be `Eq a => [[a]] -> Bool` (if it compiled in the first place).

Do you only need this to work with integers? If not, give some example as to what "complete" means in that case. If yes, then do they always start with 1?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I didn't explained myself so well. The list must always contain the element "1". The main should actually be:

main> check 1 [1,3,4,5]
main> False

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take on the problem, which uses a function that works on sorted lists, and use it with a sorted input.

The following will check that the provided list of `n` Int contains all values from `1` to `n`:

```
  check :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Bool

  import List

  check l = check_ 1 (sort l)
     where check_ n [] = True
                 check_ n [x] = n == x
                 check_ n (x:y:xs) = (x+1)==y && check_ (n+1) (y:xs)
```

Note the use of `List.sort` to prepare the list for the real check implemented in `check_`.